# how to calculate sum of numbers

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array

i have 5x5 array and a need to calculate sum of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you didn't actually declare an array in Objective-C.  However, if you declare an actual array, it should be pretty simple.  I don't have the compiler in front of me, but it should be something like this:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[ @[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], @[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], @[3, 4, 5, 6, 7], @[4, 5, 6, 7, 8], @[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]];
int sumOfFirstCol = 0;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    sumOfFirstCol += myArray[0][i];
}
```